# Local site (not localhost) isn't loaded in Firefox without being connected to the network

Tags: firefox, nginx

Initial data:

- configured nginx + php-fpm (didn't try with apache, used to nginx)
- access to the local site via alias (such as http://domain.tld/)
- there is a line in the hosts that the domain must refer to 127.0.0.1
- used only local content - without any external resources

Everything works fine, if there is a connection to the network. If it's disconnected, the site becomes unavailable. Firebug says that connection is Aborted - no error codes (code 0). But if I open that site in Google Chrome, there is no problem, everything works.

Proxy - by default.

Question: Why in Firefox, when I open the local, but not **http://localhost** site without connecting to the network, connection is aborted?